What is "illegal, immoral or improper" use in CPOL?
The The Code Project Open License contains a strange restriction in 5.f:

You agree not to use the Work for illegal, immoral or improper purposes, or on pages containing illegal, immoral or improper material.

The licence never defines what "immoral" or "improper" mean, nor does it specify any particular jurisdiction for "illegal".
Absent firm definitions of "illegal", "immoral" and "improper", it's not something a reasonable person could agree to.  So these terms seem to prevent anyone redistributing CPOL-licensed code, either as is or in derived works.  Is that the case (assuming no alternative license also applies)?
Or can I assume the legal principle that ambiguity in a contract is interpreted adverse to the drafter, so that I can apply my own definitions of these terms?

"illegal, immoral or ..." sounds like an echo of this song

An example could be using the Work to run a legal abortion clinic. Many people would consider this to be an "immoral or improper" purpose, while many others would not.

The contract mentions "Applicable Law" at the beginning, so most likely "illegal" will be read to mean "illegal for the entity who is using the Software". So, if I'm in a jurisdiction where (say) gambling is illegal, then, according to the contract, I agreed not to use the Software for that purpose.

See also this Q&A about the JSON license (famous for the "shall be used for Good, not Evil" clause): https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11308/is-org-json-a-free-open-source-library

However, as pointed out in that Q&A, the JSON license allows sublicensing, so effectively you can ignore that restriction in derivative works, whereas COPL does not allow that (so the restrictions here can't be ignored like that).

@user20574 It seems I was misled by their use of the word "Open" in the name.  And by the presence of cpol tag here.

Wow that license is a mess. 5e requires you to leave the copy of the license that's embedded in the original publication if there is one. (Which there probably is) But the definition of Articles, and the restriction in 3e on their redistribution means you need written permission from the original author to distribute said copy. Also you may not redistribute modified copies unless all modifications come from the author or the public domain. If you make any changes for your own use, you may not document them in any way that might be considered a derivative work of the original documentation. ick

@TobySpeight in fairness, the tag definition for the "cpol" tag is pretty clear that it's not open source according to either of the measures that we use.

That's not the only problem with the CPOL.  As the FSF point out,

Section 5.6 restricts how you can use the work. Section 5.4 prohibits commercial distribution of the software by itself—and depending on how you read section 3.4, you may not have permission to distribute the software by itself at all.

They conclude, and I concur, that it's a non-free licence.  Steer clear of anything so licensed.
And for the avoidance of doubt: no; if you don't clearly have the rights that you need, you're on a very dangerous slope if you assume you have them merely because you weren't clearly denied them.

I searched "FAOD"/"FAOD urban" but didn't find anything that fits. What's it mean here?

For the Avoidance Of Doubt; it's a fairly standard term in UK contract law.  Sorry about that; I used it without really thinking, due to force of habit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I suspect it is intended as a get-out-of-jail card for the person who wrote the software. If someone uses, e.g. my hotel booking software to run a brothel, I am indemnified if they are prosecuted. Moreover, if a bug in the software causes them a loss, I have a defence: they were outside the terms of their licence. This defence is at least arguable: whether it will work is a different issue.
IMHO the OP's question arose because, as engineers, we are trained to eschew ambiguity, especially in specifications. Lawyers, I suspect, are have an incentive to be ambiguous if it helps them protect their clients from liability.

I do agree that's a reasonable read of "illegal" (i.e., "I'm not responsible for downstream illegal misuse"), but I think "immoral" problematically covers all manner of legal activities, from advertising alcohol to proselytizing for an unfavorable deity, depending on who you ask.

Regarding the defense against a loss due to a bug, the license has a stronger method in it: The disclaimer of all warranties and liabilities. That will keep you safe even if you cannot claim immoral or improper use of the software.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
